# JSTL <c;>-tags not working correct when using java-objects as parameters

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jstl

In a JSP-project I use jstl-tags and it do not work correctly.

```
<%String s="michael"; %>
<p>The person's name is <c:out value="${s}" /></p>

<c:if test="${s != null}">
<%=s %>
</c:if>`enter code here`
```

this code generates: 
"The person's name is"

But when it is just jstl code it works.
Like this example

```
<c:set var="salary" scope="session" value="${2000*2}"/>
<c:if test="${salary > 2000}">
<p>My salary is: <c:out value="${salary}"/><p>
</c:if>
```

and generates "My salary is: 4000" correctly.

I have installed jstl-1.2.jar in WebContent\WEB-INF\lib
I have added this line at the top of the jsp-page...

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

I have tried to restart server, restart computer, download a new jstl-1.2.jar but nothing works.

I am not very used to work with JSP so it is possible I have missed something. Anyone have a idea or suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: That's expected. You shouldn't use scriptlets, ever. And the JSP EL doesn't deal with local variables. Only with page, request, session or application attributes.

Comment: Ok.I didn't know that.